# Check if a non-blocking send succeeded

Tags: c, sockets, io

I am making one non-blocking send call on one socket and next a blocking receive on another socket. After that I want to check if the non-blocking send succeeded or failed. How can this be done?

```
    while (i)
    {
      retval = send (out_sd, s_message, strlen (s_message), MSG_DONTWAIT);
      retval = recv (client_sd, r_message, MSG_LEN, 0);
      r_message[retval] = '\0';
      /* Here I want to wait for the non-blocking send to complete */
      strcpy (s_message, r_message);
      strcpy (r_message, "");
      i--;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a call-back?

Comment: I don't think so. Just need to check if the message sending was failed or succeeded or queued, before entering the next iteration.

Comment: Use two different var/s to store send/recv's results to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are somehow mixing synchronous and asynchronous IO, which is normally a bit confusing, but I don't see any practical problem in here.

To avoid hard polling (which is keeping looking if your operation has finished in a loop) you should use a select() to wait for your channel/socket to become available for more write operations. This would tell you that the previous one was finished (or that it was fully taken in charge by your OS, which is the same).

The select() function is the base for asynchronous IO in C, you should read about it in [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select), and [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html) is an example I think might be useful to you.

Pay attention though that select() supports read, write and exception events, the example shows a read select, you want to do a write select.

Comment: Yes i have mixed synchronous and asynchronous I/O, but in different sockets, I think this will work okay. Every process will execute this bit of code, therefore if both are blocking then there will be a deadlock. Therefore i am first sending the messages, then waiting for the receive. After one process receives data, it should check if the last non-blocking send was a success before entering into the next iteration.

Comment: I don't know the details, but if both the sockets connects the same 2 programs, are you sure you can't just use synchronous calls? Like the program A performs READ -> WRITE -> READ -> etc, and the program B performs WRITE -> READ -> WRITE -> etc. This is what is done usually, and there is no deadlock in it.

Comment: Yes that is a possibility to alternate the read and write, but i want to avoid that aspect.

Comment: I have alternated the `send` , `recv` calls depending on the connection order. Things work as per required. But still, it would be good if i could know if there is some way to check if the operation was done.

Comment: if you use synchronous calls, when they return you got a meaningful return value that tells you that. If you are using an asynchronous pattern without callbacks, the only way is to use a select (or poll/epoll) call to wait for events on that channel, and see if a "write again is possible" event shows up before an "error" event.

Comment: Sure thing: in this page [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html) you have an example on how to wait for a read channel to become available again. In the example a timeout is set to return anyway after a certain time, even if nothing happened (which is good, every second or even 10 seconds or so).

Comment: You obviously wanna do that with a write channel (to see if it has finished writing) and error (to see if something bad happened)

Answer (score 1):

`send()` will return you the number of bytes sent or `-1` in case of an error.

If there's enough buffer in the network stack to send at least some bytes from your message, `retval` will contain the number of bytes sent, which may be less than the number of bytes you wanted to send.  If the network stack buffer is full, it will contain `-1` and `errno` will be set to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.

In all cases, the send call is complete as soon as it returns.  So you do not have to wait for the non-blocking send to complete anywhere else, you need to check the return value right away after the send() call returns.